# Nothing Special, Who/What am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Me and you, we get along,
Sometimes I will start a song.
I'm quite average you say,
Showing money through the day.

I'm not from here, rather old.
Sometimes very small I'm told.
I tug you and pull you near,
Mutter now, who am I dear?

Comment: If not for the line 'showing money through the day' I would have guessed a mobile phone.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Are you:

> μ?

Me and you, we get along,

> μ and u looks alike?

Sometimes I will start a song.

> [Mu chord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_chord)

I'm quite average you say,

> Symbol for 'mean' in statistic

Showing money through the day.

> µ means the Stock Market's portfolio?
>  Edit: [NASDAQ:MU](http://google.com/finance?cid=12441984) (answer from OP)

I'm not from here, rather old.

> μ is the 12th letter of the Greek alphabet

Sometimes very small I'm told.

> it represent greek small letter me (probably wrong)
>  Edit: μ means Micro : 10<sup>-6</sup>  (credit to Moose)

I tug you and pull you near,

> Google and found [µTugs](http://bdml.stanford.edu/Main/MicroTugs)
>  Edit: μ means Magnetic permeability (credit to tmpearce)

Mutter now, who am I dear?

> µ! µµµµµµ

Comment: Mu is the metric prefix for micro, which is one millionth of the base

Comment: You've got it. See if you can find some items that are better related on money, small, and tugs. The money might be tough.

Comment: A couple of ideas: for money, mu could represent microloans; for tugs, muons have electric charge and also much more mass than an electron, so could exert more force on other objects... And I agree with Moose, mu=micro=10^-6 is the answer for "small"

Comment: Thanks all!  Edited the answers but still trying to figure out on the stock market part

Comment: @Alex The money one was a bit of a stretch. I was thinking along the lines of https://www.google.com/finance?cid=12441984. Great job!

Comment: @AggieKidd gotcha, nice riddle!

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> the Sun?

Me and you, we get along,

> Yep, the Sun is good.

Sometimes I will start a song.

> "Sunshine on my shoulders makes me happy..."

I'm quite average you say,

> The sun is an average-sized star.

Showing money through the day.

> The **gold**en sunshine?

I'm not from here, rather old.

> The Sun is 4.6 billion years old, and due to ~5 billions years of astronomical movement, was likely formed far away from "here" (wherever *that* is).

Sometimes very small I'm told.

> The sun is small compared to some stars. It's also somewhat 'small' from our vantage point.

I tug you and pull you near,

> Gravity.

Comment: +1 for some good thoughts, but no. The first line has a hidden clue, and unfortunately sunburns make me not get along with the sun.